# Custom post types with date based archive

Tags: custom-post-types, archives

I'm trying to create an archive for a custom post type. My custom post type is called `journal` and I'm running WordPress 3.3.1. My understanding is that from WordPress 3.1 this should be an included feature so navigating to `www.mywebsite.com/journal/2013` should simply return a collection of posts from 2013 using the `archive-journal.php` template. My issue is this doesn't work. I have posts from 2013 but going to that link simply returns a 404.

`www.mywebsite.com/journal/` works fine but trying to add any date filter to the end of the url with cause 404s. This is the code I'm using to register the post type. I haven't included the `$labels` array in below but it's in my `functions.php`

```
    $journal_args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'journal', 'with_front' => true),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail', 'comments'),
  ); 

register_post_type( 'journal' , $journal_args );
```

Have I missed anything? Has anyone got any idea why the date archives are not working?

Comment: Do you have update the permalink settings after activation on your code in WP? It is important, that you flush the rewrite rules.

Comment: yep tried flushing the rewrite rules didn't make any difference

Comment: If I have a custom post type named 'my_type', how can I get Wordpress to make date-based archives, for example: mysite.com/my_type/2010/
mysite.com/my_type/2010/07/
mysite.com/my_type/2010/07/28/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching I found [this](http://www.github.com/Seebz/Snippets/blob/master/Wordpress/functions/). If you register your custom post type using the function as described in the link it will add an additional date archive.